# 3 numbers in ascending order WITHOUT the use of conditional statements in Java. As in I can't use if statements at all

Tags: java

My code looks like this so far:

```
public class ThreeSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int num3 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);


        int x = Math.min(num1, num2);
        int min = Math.min(x,num3);
        int z = Math.max(num1, num2);
        int max = Math.max(z, num3);

        int a = 0;
        int mid = 0;



        while (mid >= min && mid <= max) {

        mid = a;

        }

        System.out.println(min);
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(max);



    }
```

I know how to do the min and the max but I'm having troubles with the middle one. Any idea how to do that without conditional statements?

Comment: Is it cheating to write `mid = num1 + num2 + num3 - min - max;` after you've worked out `min` and `max`?

Comment: Seems more suited to [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It wont be a solution for more then three numbers.

Comment: This seems perfect actually! I do just need to do them for 3 numbers and this is such a simple way. Thanks :)

Comment: There are just too many ways to do this without further constrains like no list allowed etc.

Answer (score 6):

in this case there is a simple algorithm for it:

> ```
> mid = Math.max(Math.min(num1,num2), Math.min(Math.max(num1,num2),num3));
> ```

Also as the operator `^` denotes bitwise `xor`. so another way is:

> `mid=num1^num2^num3^max^min;`

**EXAMPLE:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(mid(70, 3, 10));
}

static int mid(int a, int b, int c) {
    int mx = Math.max(Math.max(a, b), c);
    int mn = Math.min(Math.min(a, b), c);
    int md = a ^ b ^ c ^ mx ^ mn;
    return md;
}
```

**OUTPUT:** 10.

**Also** as OldCurmudgeon said [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28035767/823393) you can calculate the `mid` with below formula:

> ```
> int mid = num1 + num2 + num3 - min - max;
> ```

Comment: Wow.  Now all you need is to replace each `Math.max(x,y)` with `(((x-y)&Integer.MIN_VALUE)>>31)*(y-x)+x` and you're sorted!

Answer (score 3):

Put them in a List and sort it...

```
List<Integer> ints = new LinkedList<>();
ints.add(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
ints.add(Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
ints.add(Integer.parseInt(args[2]));

Collections.sort(ints); // smallest -> greatest
System.out.println(ints);

Collections.reverse(ints); // greatest -> smallest
System.out.println(ints);
```

Comment: That uses conditionals under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

```
int mid = num1 + num2 + num3 - min - max;
```

Sorry for briefness - posted from my phone.

It must be self-evident that the middle number is the sum of the three numbers minus the max minus the min. Would also work if max == mid  or max == min or even both.

Comment: a really wisely answer, I'll mention this answer in my answer if you are not agree just tell me to remove the mentioning. +1

Comment: @FarhangAmary - I'd be pleased with a mention. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is some kind of puzzle/homework are you allowed to use the ternary operator?

```
int[] ints = {3, 1, 2};
int min = ints[0] <= ints[1] && ints[0] <= ints[2]
          ? ints[0]
          : ints[1] <= ints[0] && ints[1] <= ints[2]
            ? ints[1]
            : ints[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would implement three_sort without any if statements or ternary operators. You would have to adapt this to your language of choice.

```
def two_sort(a, b):
    small = int(a < b)  * a + int(a >= b) * b
    large = int(a >= b) * a + int(a < b)  * b
    return small, large

def three_sort(a, b, c):
    a, b = two_sort(a, b)
    a, c = two_sort(a, c)
    b, c = two_sort(b, c)
    return a, b, c
```

for a more general solution:

```
from random    import randint

def two_sort(a, b):
    small = int(a < b)  * a + int(a >= b) * b
    large = int(a >= b) * a + int(a < b)  * b
    return small, large

    return li[-1]

def n_sort(li):
    for _ in li:
        for i, _ in enumerate(li[:-1]):
            li[i], li[i+1] = two_sort(li[i], li[i+1])
    return li

N = 10
li = [randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(N)]
print(N_Sort(N)(*li))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ThreeSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // command-line input
        int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b= Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int c = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);


        // compute the order

        int max=Math.max(Math.max(a,b),c);
        int min =Math.min(Math.min(a,b ), c);
        int middle = a + b + c - max - min;


        // output in ascending order

        System.out.println(min+"\n" + middle+ "\n"+ max);

    }
}
```